# Bootstrap Modal hide method needs to be submitted twice by PHP Form Submission to work

Tags: php, forms, bootstrap-4

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324397/bootstrap-modal-hide-method-keep-showing-after-form-submission)

After the mentioned question above, I tried the suggestion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477930/close-bootstrap-modal-on-form-submit). But, the modal won't hide on the first try, so I need to enter the submission twice to make it work. Here is the modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign in</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="tabel_mahasiswa.php" method="post" id="login-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Masukkan Password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="msg" style="color: red;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="button" value="loginSubmit">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the PHP code beneath:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $salt;
    $get_salt = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email'";
    $get_salt_res = $conn->query($get_salt);
    while ($row = $get_salt_res->fetch()) {
        $salt = $row['salt'];
    }
    $password = md5($_POST['password'] . $salt);
    $stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$password'";
    $res = $conn->query($stmt);
    $number_of_rows = (int)$res->fetchColumn();
    if ($number_of_rows == 1)
        echo "<script>
        $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginModal').modal('hide'); 
        return false;
    });
        </script>";
    else
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Email tidak terdaftar atau password salah, silakan coba lagi'</script>";
}
?>
```

Can anyone explaining why this thing keep happening? I've tried every solutions but none worked. Any clue would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Tugas Pendahuluan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign in</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="tabel_mahasiswa.php" method="post" id="login-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="Masukkan Password">
                    </div>
                    <div id="msg" style="color: red;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="button" value="loginSubmit">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <h4 style="color: white;"> [IF635] Web Programming </h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-right active"><a href="#">Student</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='tambah_mhs.php'" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">Tambah
                Mahasiswa
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table" id="example">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Student ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        include_once("db_config.php");
        $i = 1;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `data_mhs`";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['student_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='hapus_mhs.php?id=$row[id] '>Hapus</a> | <a href='edit_mhs.php?id=$row[id]'>Edit</a> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
        return false;
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $salt;
    $get_salt = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email='$email'";
    $get_salt_res = $conn->query($get_salt);
    while ($row = $get_salt_res->fetch()) {
        $salt = $row['salt'];
    }
    $password = md5($_POST['password'] . $salt);
    $stmt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$password'";
    $res = $conn->query($stmt);
    $number_of_rows = (int)$res->fetchColumn();
    if ($number_of_rows == 1)
        echo "<script>
        $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#loginModal').modal('hide'); 
        return false;
    });
        </script>";
    else
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Email tidak terdaftar atau password salah, silakan coba lagi'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Form and php code same in page ?

Comment: yes, form and php code is in same page. would that be a problem?

Comment: Can you set timeout in js

Comment: can you put that sentence into more detail? what I need to timeout in JS?

Comment: setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: the code doesn't do any significance.

Comment: PHP code before inserted HTML ?

Comment: Can you share full page code?

Comment: sure, you can check it now

Comment: Below posted answer check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just PHP condtion add default load model. Hope this help you.

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['email'])) { ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
        return false;
    });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```